# $l_c^\infty$ being closed, convex subset of $l^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $l_c^\infty$ consist of sequences in $l^\infty$ which are eventually $0$. (In other words, these are sequences with compact support. In other other words, these are sequences with finitely many nonzero entries.)

1) $l_c^\infty$ a closed subset of $l^\infty$?

2) Is $l_c^\infty$ a convex subset of $l^\infty$?

3) Define a function $f:l_c^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \sum^\infty_{i=1}|x_i|$. Is $f$ a convex function? Is $f$ a continuous function?

Comment: $x_n = x_{n-1} + e_{n}$ ?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to...

Comment: @Aram this sequence does not converge in $l^\infty$. Take $x_n = x_{n-1} + \frac1ne_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $l_c^\infty$ is a linear subspace of $l^\infty$.

1) no - actually this is nice source of counterexamples. This subspace is not even weak-star sequentially closed interpreted as subspace of $(l^1)^*$ with the pairing $\langle x,y\rangle_{l^1,l^\infty} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$.

To see this, take the sequence $x_n$, where $x_n$ is 
$$
x_n=(1,\frac12,\dots,\frac1n,0,\dots).
$$

2) yes - after all it is a linear subspace

3) Is is convex, since absolute value is convex. This function is not continuous, which can be seen by using the sequence of (1).

Comment: So for (1), how would I actually show that this counter example works to show that the subspace is open?

Comment: If a subspace contains just one interior point, then $0$ is an interior point, which implies that the subspace is equal to the whole space. Hence $l^\infty_c$ has no interior points at all.